# «Спасработы – явление нечастое, но запоминающееся». Верно ли слитное написание «не»?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, частица-не

«Спасработы – явление нечастое, но запоминающееся». «Но» подразумевает противопоставление, но здесь вроде как значение союза «и». Значит ли это что «нечастое» стоит писать слитно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Верно слитное написание НЕ.**
Раздельно пишется **не** с наречиями на о, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление: не далеко, а близко; ехать не быстро, а медленно. При написании не с наречиями, как и при написании не с прилагательными, следует различать прямое противопоставление, при котором один признак отрицается, а другой утверждается, и **противопоставление с уступительным оттенком значения, которое оформляется союзом** **но** (т. е. противопоставление без отрицания); ср.: говорить не громко, а тихо — говорить негромко, но понятно (т. е. тихо и понятно); Говорил не громко, не тихо, а совершенно так, как следует (Г.); Читать было неинтересно, но необходимо ([gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.57)).